# Neo4j/Cypher linked list traversal and pagination

Tags: neo4j, pagination, cypher, graph-databases, nosql

I have following structure

```
(:Post)-[:PREVIOUS]->(:Comment)-[:PREVIOUS]->(:Comment)-...->(:Comment)
```

What would be an effective way of paginating this linked list?

I assume var length expand will degrade while you're going deeper in the history. i.e.

```
MATCH (p:POST) WHERE p.Id = {id}
MATCH (p)-[:PREVIOUS*100..200]->(c)
RETURN c
```

New comments can be added and deleted. So, finding starting point by `CommentId` is not an option.

**UPDATE**

Suggested skip limit approach performs worse than variable length path expand. Hence not considered here.

```
MATCH (p:Post)-[:PREVIOUS*]->(c) 
WHERE p.Id = {id}
RETURN c SKIP 0 LIMIT 500
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're making calls to Neo4j from outside the db engine and {id} points to the most recent comment, you'd use SKIP and LIMIT to get batches of results back:

```
MATCH (p:Post)-[:PREVIOUS*]->(c) 
WHERE p.Id = {id}
RETURN c SKIP 0 LIMIT 500
```

Change the "skip" values on each call and you'll get your pagination. For instance, the second call would be SKIP 500, the third would be SKIP 1000, etc.

The REST API also has a way to batch query results between successive calls - check the REST documentation for more details.

Here's text from the REST API on paged traversals:

> Creating a paged traverser Paged traversers are created by POST-ing a
>   traversal description to the link identified by the paged_traverser
>   key in a node representation. When creating a paged traverser, the
>   same options apply as for a regular traverser, meaning that node,
>   path, or fullpath, can be targeted.

```
Example request
• POST http://localhost:7474/db/data/node/297/paged/traverse/node
• Accept: application/json; charset=UTF-8
• Content-Type: application/json
```

Comment: `SKIP LIMIT` has worse performance than var length expand that I mentioned originally (`MATCH (p)-[:PREVIOUS*100..200]->(c)`). you can check it in query planner. that's why I haven't mentioned it in the first place.

Comment: If you had mentioned trying it and it wasn't sufficiently performant then we'd both been saved some time.

Comment: sorry for not mentioning `skip limit`. REST API traversals are overkill and would need additional data processing. plus you cannot predict how client will progress through pages and set appropriate timeout to store traverser beforehand.

Comment: Then all you have left is to get the id of the last node in the current batch and pass that in as the starting point for the next batch of comments.